# text offsetting below div

Tags: jquery, css, text, vertical-alignment, cufon

this should be simple to fix--but it's not because of IE7, or at least, IE8 compatibility mode.

The text "IAN MARTIN" and "wedding photojournalism" should be tucked neatly inside the divs #lefty, #righty, and #left and #right. Instead, it's hanging out the bottom half of those divs.

It's easily fixed by having the h1 and h2 top position be around -20px, but then in IE7--the text pops up out of the top of the divs...

What to do? This does not appear to be a Cufon issue--I turned it off to test...

Could the jquery animation be messing me up? Again I don't think so, but I'm no expert...

Here's my page: http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/index-cufon-02.html

And the CSS for h1 and h2:

```
h1 {position: absolute; letter-spacing: 4px;  color: #79868e; font-family: helvetica;   font-size: 38px;}

h2 {position: absolute; letter-spacing: 4px;  color: #969696; font-family: helvetica; font-size: 38px;}
```

Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: The Cufon is on for this page, but when I turned it off, same problem for the Helvetica that it defaults to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS to h1 and h2:

`margin:7px 0 0 0;`

Works well like that here.

Comment: Bingo! And thank you! I guess that these margin settings over-ride the built in header tag margins like Mu suggests?

Comment: Exactly , all tags have built in margins defined, so you could use instead of the above a CSS Reset from here: http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/?p=187 It will make life so much easier for you man.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're telling `#left` to be 50px tall and then putting something inside it that needs 100px (38+31+31) of height, the result is that the content overflows its parent's box. You need to make the parent, `#left`, tall enough to fully contain its child `<h2>`.

However, if you set `#left` to have `height: 100px` then you'll have to reposition the "about", "testimonials", ... links to be another 50px down and you'll have to add another 50px to the height of `.field`. You'll probably have to adjust a few other `height` and `top` values as well.

You could also rework the HTML and CSS so that you don't need to absolutely position everything. Simply stacking three `<div>`s on top of each other would give you the same layout  while being less brittle; then some wrapper `<div>`s and margin settings to get it horizontally centered and offset from the top of the page.

Comment: Thank you but I'm sorry I don't understand... What are the other 31px figures coming from in the 38+31+31?

Comment: @ian_6500: That's from the default top and bottom margins on `<h2>`. The specific pixel value is browser-specific so you should set them yourself to get consistent results. Sorry, I should have been more specific about where the height was coming from.

Comment: Ah! Got it. I was wondering if there was still some mojo in play from the default header tag settings--I just assumed that by entering my own CSS for the header tags, it would switch off the CSS defaults--I was wrong.

Comment: @ian_6500: You usually start your stylesheet with a "reset everything" block just to make sure all your CSS starts in a known and consistent state. Something like this (for example): http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/